# React router capturing too many paths

Tags: react-router, create-react-app

I used `create-react-app` to bootstrap my project.

I added `react-router` to my react app. After I build and serve using `serve -s build`, when I go to any path such as http://localhost:5000/favicon.ico, it takes me to my index, which means the URL change is being captured by `react-router`. However once I'm there, if I force reload the page with CMD+SHIFT+R then the static file loads as expected. How do I make this behavior the default?

Answer (score 1):

According to the FAQ, when a site is served statically it needs to use HashRouter instead of BrowserRouter
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/FAQ.md

I also had to disable the service worker by commenting out two lines in `src/index.js` since it was caching everything all the time.

Making that change fixed my problem!